# the animation is not work

Tags: android

i have made the following animation xml file in my android project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator = "true"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<scale
 android:fromXScale = "1.0"
 android:toXScale = "0.0"
 android:pivotX="50%"
 android:pivotY="50%"
 android:duration="40000"> 
 </scale>
 </set>
```

what this is basically doing is making a view dissappear starting from its center.

Now in my code i am doing the following to start the animation:

```
overridePendingTransition (0,R.anim,myanimation);
```

but nothing is happening.

what am i doing wrong?

thank you in advance.

Comment: that when the activity closes and moves to another activity it should do so with a flip animation... the current view should flip around to show the new activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myanimation);
myView.setAnimation(a);
a.start();
```

Comment: this is when i want a view to animate, i want to add animation while moving from one activity to another.

Comment: in which case you're doing it ok, are you sure that the 40seconds you've set isn't just so long that you don't see anything before the new activity starts?

Comment: how much do you suggest i keep, to see the effect?

Comment: try some smaller values, like 2 seconds, (2000 ms)

Comment: i tried it, but it is not working. i mean i cannot see any animation.

Comment: ok, i think i understand the problem better now. firstly the xml that Deepak has provided does work better. But secondly and most importantly if you want to set the exit animation on a view you need to set it after the finish() has been called as per http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int, int)  I've just mocked up an app to test this and it works fine. Incase the link doesn't work, go to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html and search for overridePendingTransition

Comment: You could also test it by putting in your onPause() method after the super.onPause() call

Comment: how can i call the onpause method of child class before the super class?

Comment: onPause of the child is automatically called when you switch away from the activity, or close it

Answer (score 1):

try changing the animation to overridePendingTransition(R.anim.myanimation,0); and then set the timing accordingly if it helps. And also check this if it might help : http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html

Answer (score 0):

Create anim folder and paste your xml there let the name of your xml is `showview`
Reduce your animation duration from 40seconds to see the effect for testing purpose

### showview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="100%"
    android:pivotY="100%"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fillBefore="true" />
```

In your code where you want to set animation use the following code if `mImageView` is the view where you want to set animation.

```
Animation mAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.showview);
mAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.ABSOLUTE);
mImageView.startAnimation(mAnim);
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: but you don't understand,i don't want the animation to start on some view, i want it to start when i call startactivity....ie when activity is in transition...i want the old activity to flip and the destination activity should show.. like when you are flipping a coin..

Answer (score 0):

While using animation of XML file , please check some android devices have setting:

GO to **Setting** --> **Display** --> **Animation** --> enable **All Animation**